# Cloud Services vs VM deployment Cost

Tags: azure

We are working on architecture of new web application to be hosted on Azure. This application would run only in day time (Say 9AM to 5PM). What I read so far about Azure is we would continue be billed even when we stop the deployment.

However in case of Azure VM (IAAS) billing stops when we stop the VM.

> Client is keenly interested in running the IT cost to the minimum. We are planning to use WASABi/Auto-scaling block to auto shutdown & auto-start the app to run only during (9AM-5PM)

Deploying application every morning & deleting every evening even programmatically doesn't sound like a good architecture.

> Should we target the app for VM rather than Azure web role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While hourly billing cost is definitely a consideration and it is true that if you stop a VM in IaaS, billing stops, there are other considerations as well. Some of them are:

- With Cloud Services, you have to architect the application in a certain way to take advantage of statelessness there. So there may be a bit of a learning curve there. With Virtual Machines, in theory you can build an application the way you are used to and deploy that in the cloud.
- With Cloud Services, the major advantage is that you don't have to maintain the VM. This is something Microsoft does that for you. So there's little or no IT-admin overhead. With VMs, maintaining the VM is your responsibility so that's an additional cost which is recurring as well (assuming you (or your client) have an IT Admin kind of guy on the payroll).

Generally speaking, if the application is a stand-alone application with quite simple deployment topology and is brand new application it is recommended that you write them as Cloud Service but do take the costs (development / IT admin) into consideration as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you stop the virtual machine through a standard shutdown (through the machine itself for example), it does continue to incur charges. The portal will eventually show it as shutdown, but the VM still has resources allocated.

However, if you stop the machine through the portal, API, or PowerShell, it will stop and DEALLOCATE the machine. This means the VM will use storage space, but will not incur compute charges.

Simply schedule the deallocation of the machines during off-hours, and you will only page for the usage during the day.

Comment: Agree with you, so designing an architecture for web role is not an good idea in terms of cost.

Comment: Depends on the scale. If you use autoscaling with PaaS, you can have the application available 24x7 and scale down to a single instance to minimize costs.

Another option is to use a website and scale it down to the shared option during off-hours which will incur minimal costs.

But yes, IaaS sounds like the absolute best fit based on the information you provided. You get extreme flexibility in terms of configuration and pricing, but keep in mind that management of the machine is completely up to you.